# springbatch run in k8s scdf pod : Cannot load driver class: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver - Spring Cloud Data Flow(scdf)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am using spring batch running in a spring cloud data flow (k8s).

Server version : `2.9.2`

Application can run it in `local/docker`, it works fine.

But in the k8s scdf run, there is an exception.

`local log`:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:62833', transport: 'socket'

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.3)

2022-12-28 18:18:03 [main] INFO  com.xxx.batch.ArticleApp - Starting ArticleApp using Java 17.0.5 on xxxx with PID 8784 
...
2022-12-28 18:18:03 [main] INFO  com.xxx.batch.ArticleApp - The following 1 profile is active: "dev" 
2022-12-28 18:18:04 [main] INFO  com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource - {dataSource-1} inited 
2022-12-28 18:18:06 [main] INFO  com.xxx.batch.ArticleApp - Started ArticleApp in 4.317 seconds (JVM running for 4.858) 
2022-12-28 18:18:10 [main] INFO  com.xxx.batch.job.JobListener - JobListener-beforeJob task:[articleJob] params :[null] start.. 
2022-12-28 18:18:13 [main] INFO  com.xxx.batch.job.JobListener - JobListener-afterJob task [articleJob] Execution success, params :[null] 
2022-12-28 18:18:13 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO  com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource - {dataSource-1} closing ... 
2022-12-28 18:18:13 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO  com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource - {dataSource-1} closed 
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:62833', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

`docker log`:

```
2022-12-28 18:18:23 
2022-12-28 18:18:23   .   ____          _            __ _ _
2022-12-28 18:18:23  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2022-12-28 18:18:23 ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2022-12-28 18:18:23  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2022-12-28 18:18:23   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2022-12-28 18:18:23  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2022-12-28 18:18:23  :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.3)
2022-12-28 18:18:23 
2022-12-28 18:18:23 2022-12-28 10:18:23 [main] INFO  com.xxx.batch.ArticleApp - Starting ArticleApp using Java 17.0.2 on d88482e4329a with PID 1 ...
2022-12-28 18:18:23 2022-12-28 10:18:23 [main] INFO  com.xxx.batch.ArticleApp - The following 1 profile is active: "dev" 
2022-12-28 18:18:24 2022-12-28 10:18:24 [main] INFO  com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource - {dataSource-1} inited 
2022-12-28 18:18:26 2022-12-28 10:18:26 [main] INFO  com.xxx.batch.ArticleApp - Started ArticleApp in 3.87 seconds (JVM running for 4.616) 
2022-12-28 18:18:30 2022-12-28 10:18:30 [main] INFO  com.xxx.batch.job.JobListener - JobListener-beforeJob task:[articleJob] params :[null] start.. 
2022-12-28 18:18:33 2022-12-28 10:18:33 [main] INFO  com.xxx.batch.job.JobListener - JobListener-afterJob task [articleJob] Execution success, params :[null] 
2022-12-28 18:18:33 2022-12-28 10:18:33 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO  com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource - {dataSource-1} closing ... 
2022-12-28 18:18:33 2022-12-28 10:18:33 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO  com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource - {dataSource-1} closed
```

`k8s scdf pod log`:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.3)

[33m2022-12-28 08:33:58[0;39m [31m[main][0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m [36mcom.xxx.batch.ArticleApp[0;39m - [35mStarting ArticleApp using Java 17.0.2 on springbatch-article-batch1-1-zrznq0p897 with PID 1 ...[0;39m 
[33m2022-12-28 08:33:58[0;39m [31m[main][0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m [36mcom.xxx.batch.ArticleApp[0;39m - [35mThe following 1 profile is active: "dev"[0;39m 
[33m2022-12-28 08:33:59[0;39m [31m[main][0;39m [31mWARN [0;39m [36mo.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext[0;39m - [35mException encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'articleBatchJob': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jobBuilderFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Generic.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver[0;39m 
[33m2022-12-28 08:33:59[0;39m [31m[main][0;39m [1;31mERROR[0;39m [36morg.springframework.boot.SpringApplication[0;39m - [35mApplication run failed[0;39m 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'articleBatchJob': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jobBuilderFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Generic.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at com.xxx.batch.ArticleApp.main(ArticleApp.java:16)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Generic.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:410)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Generic.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
    ... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 63 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:97)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:171)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Generic.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 64 common frames omitted
```

My spring batch example configuration is as follows：
`application.yml`

```
spring:
  application:
    name: xxx-app
  profiles:
    active: dev
```

`application-dev.yml`

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://aa.bb.lab:3306/demo?useSSL=false
    username: xxx
    password: xxx
    type: com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  batch:
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: always
```

`pom.xml` :

```
    <parent>
       ...
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>article-batch</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-task</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>druid</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--        <dependency>-->
        <!--            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>-->
        <!--            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>-->
        <!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
        <!--        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

I expect it to work fine, I don't know why there is a difference in running in pod. Please advise...

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using [profile specific configuration files](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.3/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.files.profile-specific) (`application-{profile}.yml`) those settings in your `application-dev.yml` are not being used in prod as the "dev" profile is most likely not active in the prod env. It must be using MariaDB driver as the default when not specified otherwise.

To verify, create either an `application.yml` or `application-prod.yml` w/ the desired settings and see if that works.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't seem to be the problem you're describing, as I'm running it all as dev.

Comment: @CarlosLaw I misread "pod" for "prod".  I am not sure what is triggering the difference in the k8s env. I created https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/5170 to continue investigation.

Comment: @CarlosLaw Please add any info to the ticket about the k8s env (is it local too? what is the provider?).

Comment: Thank you for your help,  seems to be k8s scdf run task (springbatch) when the default will fill in some parameters, such as: `spring.datasource.url`, `spring.datasource.driver-class-name` and so on.

Comment: @CarlosLaw Did you resolve the issue? Are you passing the datasource url and classname via SCDF task configuration now?

Comment: @CarlosLaw is your SCDF instance using the mariadb as its database driver.   If so dataflow is setting the mariadb as the driver-class-name in the environment or as a command line arg (based on which entrypoint you are using) which will override your yaml.

Comment: @GlennRenfro    Thanks, similar to what you said, I have found the reason.

Comment: @CorneilduPlessis is because scdf will default to fill in some default parameters, overwriting my program on the yaml. caused by the problem